# How do I replace a model in a Backbone.Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Suppose I have a `Backbone.Collection` with three models. I want to replace the middle one, keeping the first and third models in their current positions. (Assume there's no `comparator`.) How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a good question and still relevant today, so it's worth answering.

It is possible the functionality used in my answer did not exist when you asked the question, but it is now quite straightforward to do this.

Anyway, lets assume your collection is named `myCollection` and already has 3 models stored in it. Lets also say you have a new model named `newModel` that you want use to replace the existing middle model in the collection. To replace the middle model, leaving the first and third models untouched, you can do this:

```
myCollection.remove(myCollection.at(1));

myCollection.add(newModel, {at: 1});
```

This will do exactly what you want and raise the `remove` event for the model removed and the `add` event for the replacement, which is what you wanted also.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple mechanism built into Backbone that handles this issue

`myCollection.add(newModel, {merge: true});`

Comment: Merging and replacing are different behaviours. The OP asked how to replace. However I agree that this answer is informative and addresses another need. Upvoted.

Comment: I disagree.  OP asked a specific question which this answer does not address.  Moreover, the answer does not specify that it does not address OP's original question.  It could confuse other readers.  It would be a great answer for a different question. Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a replaceAt function in the backbone collection that would look something like this:

```
   replaceAt : function(model, options, replaceIndex) {
      this._replaceAt(model, options, replaceIndex);
      return this;
    },

   _replaceAt : function(model, options, replaceIndex) {

      options || (options = {});
      if (!(model instanceof Backbone.Model)) {
        model = new this.model(model, {collection: this});
      }
      var already = this.getByCid(model);
      if (already) throw new Error(["Can't add the same model to a set twice", already.id]);
      this._byId[model.id] = model;
      this._byCid[model.cid] = model;
      model.collection = this;
      replacedModel = this.at(replaceIndex)
      this.models.splice(replaceIndex, 1, model);
      this._cleanModel(replacedModel, options);
      model.bind('all', this._boundOnModelEvent);
      if (!options.silent) model.trigger('add', model, this, options);
      return model;
    },

    _cleanModel : function (model, options) {
      if(!model) return null;
      delete this._byId[model.id];
      delete this._byCid[model.cid];
      delete model.collection;
      if(!options.silent) model.trigger('remove', model, this, options);
      model.unbind('all', this._boundOnModelEvent);
      return model;
    },
```

Its based on the _add and _remove methods.  It should fire the appropriate events that you are looking for but I didn't test for that.  I tested that it would replace an element in the collection at the appropriate place.

(using backbone .3.3)

Comment: Hmm, so maybe I should write a `LinearCollection` subclass for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to modify the `collection.models` array directly, then call

```
collection.refresh(collection.models)
```

However, this will invoke an `add` event listing every model. Ideally, I'd want to invoke a `remove` event for the model that's removed and an `add` event for the new one. I'm not sure whether that's possible without using a `comparator` and adding indices on my models...

Answer (score 0):

Although of this question asked a lot of time ago, it relevant even for today.
And actually its very easy.

1. we need to get the old model index inside the collection.
2. and then add the new one into the collection at the same index position and merge

look in the example below:

```
 var index = collection.indexOf(oldModel); //1  
 collection.add(newModel, {at: index, merge: true}); //2
```

Hope it would help somone ...
good luck !

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. Used with `collection.set`, `merge: true` takes the attributes of the new model and `set`s them on the existing model at the target index. Used with `collection.add`, it has no effect (at least in Backbone 1.1.0).

Comment: Hi Trevor, I had this discussion with a friend and i pointed him to this link: [backbone add collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) in the backbone official site. and by the way I tried the above code and its working. Anyway thank you for the feedback.